# python readline strange behaviour

Tags: python, readline

The text file dummy.txt contains the following lines:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

The following program is supposed to append each line to the lines list.

```
f1 = open('c:\Python33\dummy.txt')
lines = []
for line in f1:
    lines.append(f1.readline())
f1.close()
print(lines)
```

But its output is:

> > > ['Line 2\n', '']

When I use the IDLE, open the file then and type `lines.append(f1.readline())` three times then print lines, I get what I wanted, namely `['Line 1\n', 'Line 2\n', 'Line 3\n']`.

What is going wrong with the program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`open` will return a generator which you're getting the next line correctly but you're getting it twice for a loop. So this is what you're doing... You're calling `f1` in the loop then in the append `f1` is being called again pulling the second line. Last you call it in the loop header again calling the third line then when you call it again in the apped you're getting the end of file. which ends the generator.

Do this:

```
f1 = open('c:\Python33\dummy.txt')
lines = []
for line in f1:
    lines.append(line)
f1.close()
print(lines)
```

or

```
lines = [line for line in f1]
```

or

```
lines = f1.readlines()
```

Comment: I am obliged to you, Jeff, for your explanation. What I didn't pick up from the Python documentation was that "open()" produced what is in effect an iterator, so all the lines are already there in f1 just waiting to be read. Thank you, Sir.